# Missing "Ship-to Name" in orders?

Tags: magento2

For some reason, occasional orders are missing the "Ship-to Name" and other information related to the Shipping Address. Can you think of any reason why this would be happening, and how to prevent this?

To my knowledge, there'd be no way for the user to checkout on the website without the Shipping Address filled out, so I can't pinpoint what might be different about these specific orders.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Edit: Shipping and Handling information is also absent from these orders.

Also, these orders are marked as completed automatically (vs. "processing")